# I can't figure out how this loop not breaking and give the right value. It just keeps adding up

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, nested-loops, break

> Code to bring copy the unique value from array A to B.
> And return the number of unique value which is the number of element in B

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func(int A[], int B[], int n)
{
 int i, j, inc = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(A[i] == A[j])
            
                break;
```

> this break supposed to break out the inner loop incrementally

```
        if(i == j)
        {
            B[inc] = A[i];
            inc++;
        }
        }
     
    }
  
 
}
int main()
{
    int A[100] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0};
    int B[100];
    int c;
    c = func(A, B, 10);
    printf(" %d", c);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where's the `return` value specified in your function ? `inc` isn't going to make its way back to `main` by magic.

Comment: Even when you add the missing `return inc;` line in your `func`, you still have the problem that the `if(A[i] == A[j])` will **always** be true on the first iteration of the inner loop ... because `i` and `j` will be the same (both zero).

Comment: `if (i == j)` in the inner loop is equally pointless. By definition of the limiter of the inner loop `i` and `j` will *never* be equal there. If anything it belongs in the outer loop, outside (and after) the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test for `i` against `j` is misplaced. It belongs outside, but after, the inner loop. And, of course, you need to return `inc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func(int A[], int B[], int n)
{
    int i, j, inc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (A[i] == A[j])
                break;
        }
        if (i == j)
        {
            B[inc] = A[i];
            inc++;
        }
    }
    return inc;
}

int main()
{
    int A[100] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0};
    int B[100];
    int c;
    c = func(A, B, 10);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    for (int i=0; i<c; ++i)
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

**Output**

```
6
1 3 4 5 2 0
```

That is the correct answer. there are six unique values in the source array, 0...5 inclusively.

Comment: My poor eyes are just too sore. Stuck here for like an hour. I'm kinda mindlessly staring at things. Should I rest when things going sour?